# Scrollable content inside an HTML does not scroll in android emulator or phone

Tags: android, html, css, android-layout, webview

I have a WebView that displays some HTML content. Inside my HTML I have placed overflow-y: scroll for a particular div. Now when the number of items exceed the area of the div the div does not scroll. Anyone having any idea, please suggest.

overflow-y: auto doesn't help either.

Comment: In my experience, this does not work on Android 2.x devices, though it seems to work fine on ICS.

Comment: Yes, Seems to be a problem with the webview.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with Android. Maybe the WebView is unable to support the scrollable div element.

Found a possible solution at the following link:
http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/scroll-div.htm

Worked for me. Hopefully it will work for you guys. Cheers

Comment: Which solution from that page?

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using ScrollView in your xml?

Comment: As the content is inside the HTML you cannot put a ScrollView.