# Detect inner scroll using javascript in android

Tags: javascript, android, html, touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scrollable content inside an HTML does not scroll in android emulator or phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276904/scrollable-content-inside-an-html-does-not-scroll-in-android-emulator-or-phone)

I have the two nested div and has the scroll bar also. It works fine in browser but while using this in touch devices, the outer scroll only works but inner scroll cannot work.

```
<div id='parentscroll' style='overflow: auto;height: 100px'> 
   something
   <div id='innerscroll' style='overflow: auto;height: 50px'>
     something
   </div>
</div>
```

The above is my coding i try to scroll the inner element, but the parent element only scrolls while touch.

Is there any way to scroll the inner content also.?

Comment: in a web view? or are you developing an html5 app?